# Archive options in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, archive

If I want to archive a doc library, I'd create a new doc library, create new column "doc status" and use SP Designer to make workflow for any doc status=expire> move it to "archive doc library" (also I'm not familiar with SP designer).

This solution is not appropriate as if I have 10 doc library in each subsite, it will require to create 10 new "archive doc library" to archive files.

I want to archive entire site or subsite, so by the end of the project life cycle, arcive contents, then delete the current project.

Comment: Please be clear. What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have two requirements both of which can be addressed with SharePoint 2013:

1. If you want to have a common Archival/Retention Policy for documents across your site, you might want to create a content type and enable its settings in Information management policy settings -> Enable Retention and move the files to a site like Records Centre.
2. Site Retention is introduced in 2013. Once you are done with part 1, you can enable this on your site to delete the sites automatically.

Please see this blog for more details: http://www.future-processing.pl/blog/retention-policy-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: i have 1 site collection which has subsites(HR,IT,sales,.,.) how to automatically configure sending files to Record Center? should i "Enable Retention" on each doc library?

if i enabled site policy for 2 years, the site will be Closed and deleted automatically. how can i send the site to Record center instead?

Comment: If you want to send records to records follow the below steps:

1. Configure Connection: You can follow steps in http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/configure-send-to-connections-in-sharepoint-2010/

2. Stages: Go to the Content Type for the documents you want to move, add a first stage of record in Enable Retention under Information Policy to 'declare the documents as records'. Add a second stage in policy and send the records to the site in the first step by selecting 'Transfer to another location'

Comment: You can only send documents to records centre. You cannot send sites to records centre. If you want to take back-up of sites then you have to create schedule jobs to save sites in a location.

Mark as answer if the above answers your question.

Comment: what i understand, after creating a send to connector to Record Center, (i don't have Content Types defined, users just upload different office doc to the libraries). how to create IMP Retention Policy for all sites without using Content Types?

Comment: If you have not specified any content type then by default, SharePoint associates it to 'item' content type. So, set the retention policy for it. You can find it under site content types in site settings.